# pymongo update_one not updating based on _id

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have this change set:

```
change_set = {'name': 'bso save job again', 'location': 'new york city', 'expires': '2020-04-04', 'created': '2020-03-05'}
```

with this id (i'm not creating this id, it is actually from an earlier save):

```
id = '5e6107ddfef5aa3c2e3647b2'
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
result = dbjobs.update_one({'_id': id}, {'$set': change_set})
```

my result.raw_result is this:

```
{'n': 0, 'nModified': 0, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': False}
```

Its not throwing an error, I'm just getting zero change.  Am I updating wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: your `id` should be of type `ObjectId` and not `string`.

Add this to your code:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
id = ObjectId('5e6107ddfef5aa3c2e3647b2')
```

Short explanation for debugging such issues:

From looking at the return value of `update_one` specifically the  `ok` field returns 1, meaning the operation succeeded.

Combine that with the fact that `n=0` meaning that Mongo is not able to match any documents, hence the problem is in the query section of the operation.